# Where is the Zimbra Talk roster located in Ubuntu?

Tags: zimbra, zimbra-talk

I currently have Zimbra Talk installed, and I have it configured to pull from a specific distribution list from our Zimbra mail server.

However, this list doesn't get updated in our chat buddy list when users are added/removed.

So, I'm trying to find the location of this stored list on the zimbra talk server to see if I can updated it via cron or some other process.